# How can I launch public alternative (not private) chain on Ethereum protocol

Tags: protocol, project-fork

What if I want to launch independent network using Ethereum protocol because current prices are too high for my purposes. Is that possible without forking and maintaining new codebase using `geth` or `eth` or `ethereumj`? What is the best tool for this?

Comment: This question could use some elaboration. Not sure what you mean by the 'current prices are too high'? The gas price for compute resources? As long as you provide some gas your transaction should eventually be completed: https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethereum-Development-Tutorial#gas

Comment: You can fork the code and see if someone follows...

Comment: @GrokSrc By current prices I mean that there is a network with >500 Gh/s and >1k of nodes. I am asking about a case when my purpose need to: (1) put amounts of data into public blockchain, (2) don't need to process it through such powerful network, (3) is ok if data will be processes through 50 nodes less expensive network and (4) don't need to reinvent a wheel.

Comment: @Symeof Forking is not an answer. I am following a project since inception and one of Serenity feature is abstraction that is exactly about that.

Comment: You could edit your question to incorporate the information you gave GrokSrc.
(1) it's seldom necessary to lots of data into the public blockchain; instead you should use IPFS and only store the hashes in the blockchain, or even just the root of the merkle tree of your data.
For (2) and (3) and (4), it should be solved once the scalability solutions are implemented; but then it really depends how much trust you need and how much you are willing to pay. There are cheaper, more centralized systems for smart contracts.

Comment: @21xhipster Forking has been suggested but you are looking specifically for an answer related to Serenity.  I suggest closing this one and asking your question specifically.  Also, if you are simply concerned about gas prices, please ask that question itself and your question will be clearer.